# Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'allow-from https is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, x-frame-options

In chrome it is having issue to redirect based on this option allow from in aspx page

Answer (score 0):

ALLOW-FROM is generally not very well supported: https://caniuse.com/?search=allow-from

The good news is that you can set X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM that works for IE11 and also set Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors directive that works for all the others. When frame-ancestors is set, X-Frame-Options is ignored, so you will not get that error message.